# Selecting MF or HCA returns always error 6E 00 - Class 'CLA' no supported - for eGK

Tags: java, smartcard, apdu, smartcard-reader

I have seen a number of topics on the subject. Most of them suggest that CLA sent to the card reader is wrong.
However, I am using codes described in German documentation for the card (Implementierungsleitfaden zur Einbindung der eGK in die Primärsysteme der Leistungserbringer v1.6.0 from 21.10.2013).
According to that doc (point 5.4.4.1) I should sent:
**00 A4 04 0C 07 D2 76 00 01 44 80 00**
to select MF or
**00 A4 04 0C 06 D2 76 00 00 01 02**
to select HCA

in both cases I get 6E 00 error.
Commans such as:

- Request iCC (20 12 01 01 XX)
- or Reset CT (20 11 00 00 00)

from the same doc, work just fine.

Any idea why do I get **CLA not supported** - could it be for example because there is not data on the card and if so how can I check it?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Note: eGK is not necessarily javacard, if I remember correctly, native card suppliers were the majority. An uninitialized card card would react exactly like you describe, so this explanation is my first choice. If it is not initialized, the eGK specification is of no help: it describes only the complete product, whereas a raw card is heavily supplier-dependent. I would ask the party, which delivered your card for additional insights. Otherwise the ATR is all you have.

Comment: I just got information that they have real data stored in them - so they should be ready to read (they were attached to the card reader and it looks like they imitate real insurance cards which I'm after.
I now wonder if maybe I am missing some step between request/reset and the attempt to select file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason was obvious but since it was my first time with card readers I did not see it for long time: I was sending ICC commands (like select file) to to CT (JavaCTAPI.CT) whereas I should be sending them to ICC1 (JavaCTAPI.ICC1).

In other words I was doing this:

```
ctData(..., JavaCTAPI.CT, ..., ..);
```

whereas I should have been doing this:

```
ctData(..., JavaCTAPI.ICC1, ..., ..);
```